# ConstraintLayout : How to create this layout using the ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I want to create this layout using the ConstraintLayout:

[image]

The "My Device" lies in the top-left corner, the "Bedroom" lies in the top-right corner, the user icon lies in the left of the layout, below "My Device". These 3 items are ok with ConstraintLayout. The problem is the center-right content area, include the "20:30" and an imageview.

I want them lie in the area that below "Bedroom" and "My Device", and to right of the user icon. My layout file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="255dp"
android:layout_height="@dimen/device_main_page_grid_item_height"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_white_bg_2"
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
android:transitionName="card_in">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_num1"
    style="@style/device_main_grid_item_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="@dimen/list_title_default_title_fade_edge"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="none"
    android:text="My Device"
    android:textColor="@color/class_V"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_13sp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/tv_num"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_num"
    style="@style/device_main_grid_item_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_gray_bg_3"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
    android:text="Bedroom"
    android:textColor="#FF999999"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_11sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_num1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:src="@drawable/default_avatar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1,1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_num1" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/devider_line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_num1"
    />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/right_bottom_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/devider_line"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/icon"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shortcut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/operation_open_close"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/kuailian_confirm_loading_filled"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/shortcut"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:text="20:30"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ckb_edit_selected"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_icon_selector"
    android:button="@null"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:maxWidth="8dp"
    android:maxHeight="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1,1"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

However, the preview of the layout is below in android studio:

[image]

It seems the center-right content area overlaps with the "Bedroom", and is not below the "Bedroom", which it should be.

How to create this layout using ConstrantLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can make something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="255dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myDevice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My device"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myDevice"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clock"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="20:30"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/img1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/img1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/img1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/img2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Bedroom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bedroom"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/myDevice"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/Bedroom"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/clock"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Result that you will get be like:

[image]

Comment: you can change `android:layout_height` of img2 to 30dp for example. Also I suggest to you use the text editor and create constraint layout via text tab and not from Design tab